# What is meant by "set bang"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms

What is meant by **"set bang"** in the following sentence:

*The tasteful and triangular green is **set bang** in the middle of the large village.*

Thank you.

Comment: Have you done some minimal research about the possible meanings of "bang"? What about "(adverb) (informal UK) exactly"?

Comment: According to (dictionary.com):
precisely: bang in the middle of the road
So, does it mean that (The tasteful and triangular green is set precisely in the middle of the large village.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're grouping the words together incorrectly. "Set bang" is not an expression. The expression is "*bang in the middle*".

"*Bang in the middle*" means the precise centre of something. A similar idiom is "*dead centre*".

Comment: Another similar usage is "smack in the middle of".